My first person movement moves in world space, not local space
Basically it works perfect except the fact that it moves in world space and not local space I need it to move depending on the orientation
// Alright this is basic walking nice

float hInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float vInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

Vector3 movement = new Vector3(hInput, 0f, vInput);

rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * Time.deltaTime);

I tried doing a orientation setup but I'm bad with Vectors

add the line movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement); before sending the movement to the rigidbody.. this converts the movment

@BugFinder in that case I would even get rid of any transform usage (just to not get confused/tempted to use it for other things) and rather do rb.rotation * movement .. neither will work if scaling is involved and you want to move in real local space taking the size differences into account as well .. in which case you would need TransformVector instead

Ok so I figured it out I used movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement); and then I did Vector3 movement = new Vector3(vInput, 0f, -hInput);. So the complete code block is `float hInput =Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
+


// Alright this is basic walking nice
float hInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float vInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

Vector3 movement = new Vector3(vInput, 0f, -hInput);

movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);

rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * Time.deltaTime);



